# ASP NET CORE MVC My cookie is null, but it doesn't seem to be

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

So I want to store list of articles in cookies to make a shopping cart. I copy-pasted below the key elements of my code. In the method Buy I create the cookie if it doesn't existed earlier, but after that it is still null apparently.

```
public ActionResult Buy(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (Request.Cookies[strCart] == null)
            {
                List<Cart> lsCart = new List<Cart>();
                lsCart.Add(new Cart(_context.Articles.Find(id), 1));
                cartAmount++;
                SetCookie(strCart, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lsCart), 600);
            } else
            {
                List<Cart> lsCart = (List<Cart>)Helper.GetObjectFromJson<List<Cart>>(Request, strCart);
                int check = isExistingCheck(id);
                if (check == -1)
                {
                    lsCart.Add(new Cart(_context.Articles.Find(id), 1));
                    cartAmount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    lsCart[check].ArticleQuantity++;
                    cartAmount++;
                }
                SetCookie(strCart, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lsCart), 600);
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

**SetCookie method:**

```
public void SetCookie(string key, string value, int? numberOfSeconds = null)
        {
            CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
            if (numberOfSeconds.HasValue)
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(numberOfSeconds.Value);
            Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, option);
        }
```

**GetObjectFromJson method:**

```
 public static class Helper
{
    public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this HttpRequest request,string key)
    {
        var value = request.Cookies[key];
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }

}
```

**Upper part of my Index.cshtml file where I get error:**

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    List<Cart> articles = (List<Cart>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cart>>(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Cart"]);
}
```

**Error:**

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
> Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(object
> value, string parameterName)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value, Type type,
> JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value,
> JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value)
> AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_ShoppingCart_Index.ExecuteAsync() in
> Index.cshtml
>
> ```
> List<Cart> articles = (List<Cart>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cart>>(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Cart"]);
> ```

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context)

**EDIT:**

**This is how my Program.cs file looks like (I use .net 6.0 so there is no Startup.cs):**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.Name = "Shop";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1440);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSession();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned code from Program.cs/ Startup.cs, I do not want to assume that you have enabled cookies.

If not, please try something like.

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.Name = "YOURAPPNAME";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1440);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Comment: I have just added my Program.cs file. Unfortunately it still does not work.